# IronPython call method by name

Tags: dynamic, ironpython

Is there any way to call method by name and specify arguments without using dynamic? (C#)

**UPDATE:**

`
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
            ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();

```
        engine.ExecuteFile("script.py", scope);

        dynamic calculator = scope.GetVariable("Calculator");
        dynamic calculatorInstance = engine.Operations.CreateInstance(calculator);
        dynamic result = engine.Operations.InvokeMember(calculatorInstance, "sample");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

`

`class Calculator:
    def sample(self):
        return 'test'`

That works great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ObjectOperations` class to perform dynamic operations, and you can get an instance of it from a `ScriptEngine` instance:

```
ScriptEngine engine = ...;
object result = engine.Operations.InvokeMember(o, "foo", 1, 2, "3");
```

Answer (score 0):

Open Source Impromptu-Interface (can be found in nuget) has a bunch of methods for doing [reflection-like invocation](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding) on any dynamic object, python, ruby, c#, etc, as it uses the dlr c# binder code.

```
 Impromptu.InvokeMember(o, "foo", 1, 2, "3")
```

But in this case, JeffHardy's answer is best, since you are already working with a script engine.