# Need an easy way to embedd IronPython with C++ CLI

Tags: c#, c++, command-line-interface, ironpython

So I found [this guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2009/10/25/hosting-ironpython-in-a-c-4-0-program.aspx#comments) for doing it in `C#` and it worked flawlessly, very very easy to set up. Now I've been trying to do the same thing in `C++/CLI` as he only codes in `C++/CLI` and it's turning out to be a lot more complicated..

First of all there is no dynamic keyword in `C++/CLI` so translating the code example from that guide didn't really seem to work. I found [another example](http://oldschooldotnet.blogspot.se/2011/04/scripting-ccli-with-ironpython-visual.html) specifically for `C++/CLI` but it doesn't actually work anymore, I'm guessing it is for an old version of IronPython. So I really need some help with just an easy way to run an IPY script from within `C++/CLI` and then maybe an example on how to expose objects/methods to the script.

Comment: Yes, there's a mountain of code that's underneath *dynamic* in the C# language.  Both in the compiler and the DLR binder in Microsoft.CSharp.dll.  Completely invisible to the unaided eye.  But you can see what's going on when you use ildasm.exe to look at the generated MSIL.  Which should be enough to convince you that you'll have to climb Mount Everest first before you'll get this going in C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible (I've never done it with C++/CLI), but you'll just have to do it [the old fashioned, pre-.NET 4 way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8970458/ironpython-call-method-by-name/8975227#8975227) (in C#):

```
ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
engine.Execute(fooScript, scope);
object foo = scope.GetVariable("foo");
object result = engine.Operations.Invoke(foo, 1, "a");
```

Sprinkle ^ in there as appropriate to convert the C# to C++/CLI.

(fooScript, in this case, would contain something like:

```
def foo(a, b):
    return str(a) + ", " + str(b)
```

)